# Can we use g++ compile code to do performance analysis with Solaris Studio's Performance Analyser?

Tags: c++, c, solaris, sunstudio

I am getting the following error while running the collect command

$ collect -c on sample
bit (warning): Cannot operate on /home/user1/ANALYSIS/SAMPLE_PROGRAM/sample. Ple                                                                                      ase recompile it on a machine with Solaris10 update 5 or higher (or OpenSolaris                                                                                         version snv_52 or higher). If using an older OS, try -xbinopt=prepare (SPARC onl                                                                                        y).

The sample program was build with following g++ flags

g++ -c -Wall -g3 -m64 -pthread -O2 -DSOLARIS -DSS_64BIT_SERVER

The sample program is simple
contains only the following code
`while (true)
{
sleep (10);
}`

I was just trying to see whether c++ code compiled code can be used with collect command.
As we have a huge g++ compiled binary which we would not like to compile again with Solaris Studio C++ compilers

Comment: Tried collect without -c option i.e. not to include count stats and it worked for basic collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Studio option `-xbinopt=prepare` includes special code to binaries to use performance counters. I haven't been using it for years... as far as I remeber `-xbinopt=prepare` makes binary to write perfomance data to files in CWD (or dir specified by other parameter) and late you can use those data with `-xbinopt=use`.
Rules are compile 1st with *prepare*, then run to collect data, later recompile with collected performance data to get better optimized code. Similar to JIT compiler, but in compile time.